# How to access a variable stored in another method in java in the same class

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I need to access the variable "value" in the second method. I tried making it an instance variable but it just returned as a null.

```
public class RateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage extends PageObject {

@FindBy(xpath = "actual xpath")
private WebElementFacade checkbox;

@FindBy(xpath = "actual xpath")
private WebElementFacade fellowRated;   

private String value;

public void selects_first_checkbox() {
    value = checkbox.getValue();
    System.out.println(value);
    checkbox.click();
}

public void verifyFellowDisplayed() {
    String fellow = fellowRated.getTextValue();
    System.out.println(fellow);
    assertThat(fellow.equalsIgnoreCase(value));
    System.out.println(value);
}
}
```

Here is the code that calls these methods

```
public class RateFellowUnsatisfactorySteps extends ScenarioSteps {

private RateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage rateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage;

@Step
public void selectsFirstCheckbox(){
    rateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage.selects_first_checkbox();
}

@Step
public void verifyFellowDisplayed(){
    rateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage.verifyFellowDisplayed();
}
}
```

Comment: what you are doing here looks fine.  What prints when this line is hit in first function?: System.out.println(value);   (when making a private instance variable like this you may want to create getvalue()/setvalue() functions... so you can access it from outside the class...)

Comment: @pcalkins in the first method, it will print the fellow ID number. I need that same fellow ID number to be compared against the one that is retrieved in the second method. At that point the value of the String value becomes null.

Comment: maybe you have two instances of this class... you need to include the code that calls the methods.

Comment: @pcalkins just did that

Comment: Initialize by calling the constructor... so rateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage = new RateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage();  Right now you just have references to a class, but not really any instances of that class. (?)

Comment: I think as you have it now, it's just a typed object.  It's a type that contains those methods, but you haven't created an instance.

Comment: @pcalkins just tried that, still returns as null.

Comment: Possibly due to order the steps are called?  Would need to include more code to see when the steps are called.

Comment: You sure those methods weren't set as static?  Seems like the method calls shouldn't have worked before.

Comment: @pcalkins no the method calls were never static. Also to answer your other question, yes the steps are not called in that order. There are several other methods that are called in between that I have excluded. Do you think that may be the issue? The fact that these two steps are not in sequential order?

Comment: "value" will be null if verifyFellowDisplayed is called before selects_first_checkbox

Comment: @pcalkins no so selects_first_checkbox is called before verifyFellowDisplayed. But there are other methods called after selects_first_checkbox and before verifyFellowDisplayed

Comment: just to be clear, you have to call  rateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage = new RateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage(); in the constructor of the class that defines selectsFirstCheckbox method.  Right now you have no constructor there... and it's unclear where/when that class's constructor is called.  You may also want to mention what framework you are using here?

Comment: I may be leading you down the wrong path for your framework.  Maybe the easier thing to do would be get rid of your "value" property entirely.  Just use checkbox.getValue(); when you need it.

Comment: @pcalkins Yea unfortunately it's not an option because these two methods are used on two different pages so I can't just use it when I want. I need to be able to store the value of that string on one page and compare it to the string on another page.

Comment: I would check your framework's documentation there... not sure where you'd be storing things like that.  They seem to be using class objects without creating new references.  There may be an annotation or something you can use to persist variables... or you'd return it from a step method and set it in your "test" class instance, wherever that may be.  I suppose that would be whatever holds the "steps".

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing looks correct.  Are you sure that selects_first_checkbox has been called already at the point that you're calling verifyFellowDisplayed for this instance of RateFellowUnsatisfactoryPage?  Obviously, if it has not yet been set, it will still be null.

Assuming it has been called, is it being called in the same thread?  Java will sometimes optimize away references to member variables.  Try declaring it volatile, which should fix it as long as you're using (I think) Java 8 or higher.  If that doesn't fix it, try declaring it to be AtomicReference and you'll have an extra step to access it.  Sorry, but I forget exactly what.  The point of AtomicReference is that it will not optimize away any reference to it.

Comment: An AtomicReference combined with only get/set is equivalent to a volatile variable. Check the implementation. The internal field is volatile and the get and set do a volatile read and volatile write respectively.

Comment: @pveentjer That was always the intent of volatile, but it wasn't actually true until (I think) Java 8.  Before then, most Java compilers didn't actually implement it, which is why old-timers like me are still more comfortable with AtomicReference.

Comment: The Java Memory Model has been completely updated with JSR-133 in Java 5. The AtomicReference was added in Java 5 and there never was any difference between an AtomicReference and a volatile. I'm also an old-timer btw. I started out with Java 1.1.

[edit] Ok, with 30 years of experience you are beating me (feeling young).